# How to play sound by onTouch and stop when fingures up

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

When I touch on Image, the media player starts but on removing fingure from that image, media playes does'nt stop.Please help me guys.

iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.air);

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.airhorn_1);
            mp1.start();
            mp1.setLooping(true);
            mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp1.release();
                }
            });

            Log.i("Action", "Down");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i("Action", "Move");


            Log.i("On Long", "On Long");

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            mp1.pause();

            Log.i("Action", "Cancel");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            mp1.pause();
            //mp1.stop();
            Log.i("Action", "up");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You should just be able to call mp1.stop(), does this not work? Try  mp1.stop();
mp1.release();
mp1 = null;
To fully release it on Action Up.

Comment: When I am taking my finger up some time it does not stop. but some time it stops.

Comment: Its giving an error on double Tap.

Comment: Trying using the .IsPlayingMethod to check if it is playing, if it is stop it. Ill add an answer with the check.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onTouch(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            } else {
                mp.start();
            }
```

This will check when you Touch the ImageView if the Media Player is playing, if it is it will stop it, if not it will start it. With this you shouldn't need to use the switch case.

Be sure to set up your media player before this.