# Playing Audio in Android onTouch

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media-player, ontouch

I am writing code to play a sound and vibrate when a user touches the screen and when he lift his finger up the vibration and the sound stops.
Help required to play the audio ... everything is working including vibration but the audio is not played...
the audio file name is tr.mp3

this is my code:-

```
package dynamitechetan.trimmersimulator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
     b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
             if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                 vb.vibrate(1000 * 60 * 10);//10mins
                 b.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);

 //                     mp.seekTo(0);
//
////                    mp.reset(); 
//                     mp.start();
                 try {
                     mp.reset();
                     AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                     afd = getAssets().openFd("tr.mp3");
                     mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                     mp.prepare();
                     mp.start();
                 }  catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }


                 return true;
             }
             if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                 vb.cancel();

                     mp.stop();


                 b.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                 return false;
             }
             return false;
         }

     });

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

Inside **Oncreate()**

```
mp= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tr);
```

Music file should be in your **raw** directory

**To start music**

```
mp.start();
```

Comment: when i am writing mp.start() inside onCreate() method the sound plays ... but when I write inside the onTouch method it does not.

Comment: If you start it on  onCreate, that means it been played on till the app is destroyed..You need to stop it or pause it accordingly....

Comment: I know that .. but i want to play the audio when I touch the screen not when the app is started and for that this code is not working

Comment: here this link will sort you out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861437/how-to-play-sound-by-ontouch-and-stop-when-fingures-up